# forced Helmholtz equation eigenfunctions: $\frac{dU}{dx^2} + k^2U = f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$\frac{dU}{dx^2} + k^2U = f$ with $U(0)=U(\pi)=0$ where $K \notin \mathbb{Z}$

I can't see why:

the eigenfunctions are $\phi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}sin(nx)$ and eigenvalues

$\lambda_n = k^2 - n^2$ for $n=1, 2 ...$

Solving the homogeonous equation and using $U(0)=0$ gives $U= Asin(kx)$ but since $K \notin \mathbb{Z}$ im not sure how to continue?

Answer (score 1):

You are solving the eigenvalue problem
$$ U''+k^2U = \lambda U \quad\iff\quad U''+(k^2-\lambda)U = 0 $$
with the boundary conditions $U(0)=U(\pi) = 0$.

Assuming that $\lambda < k^2$, the general solution of the equation above is given by
$$ U(x) = A\cos(x\sqrt{k^2-\lambda}) + B\sin(x\sqrt{k^2-\lambda}). $$
From $U(0)=0$, we see that $A=0$, so
$$ U(x) = B\sin(x\sqrt{k^2-\lambda}) .$$
From $U(\pi)=0$, we get
$$ 0 = U(\pi) = B\sin(\pi\sqrt{k^2-\lambda}). $$
If $\lambda$ is to be an eigenvalue, we must require that $B\not=0$ (since otherwise $U\equiv0$ cannot be an eigenvector). This forces
$$ \sin(\pi\sqrt{k^2-\lambda})=0 \quad\iff\quad \sqrt{k^2-\lambda}\; \text{ is an integer}. $$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Ok thanks, i can see how that gives the eigenvalue but i am still stuck on how to calculate the coeff B?

Comment: $B$ is just a normalization constant that one obtains by requiring that $$ 1= \vert U\Vert^2 = \int_0^{\pi} |U|^2 \,\mathrm dx. $$ Don't forget to eliminate the case when $\lambda \geq k^2$ (since the solution I presented holds only for $\lambda < k^2$).

Comment: Brilliant thanks mate!!